# How can I get my stashed files back to where it was before stash?

Tags: tortoisegit

I got a pop-up in my git "The current working tree is not clean. do you want to stash the changes?" It had two options stash and abort i selected "stash" now I don't see my previous changes in my commit list how can I get my changes back? Please answer emergency!!!!!!

Comment: you can try adding screenshot of your git editor mostly stashed code is displayed at one of the section in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Open the context menu in explorer on the repository. Then go to the TortoiseGit submenu and select "Stash Pop".

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-stash.html

Answer (score 0):

use below command to get back the stashed files :

```
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is looking for the "stash list" and "stash pop" context menu items. Windows 11 hides some menu items by default :D, so when you right-click, first choose "Show more options" and all items in Tortoise's context menu will appear.

[image: windows 11 tortoise git context menu screenshot]